# Laravel extend the default web authentication guard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-authentication

I'm using the default laravel authentication but now I need to **add** the possibility to login directly to my app using a link with a specific token passed as GET param.

The [`Auth::viaRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#closure-request-guards) function seems to be a good way to approach this problem

```php
Auth::viaRequest('custom-auth', function ($request) {
   if ($defaultGuardWorks) {
      return $userFromDefaultGuard;
   }
   
   if (!empty($request->get('auth-token')) {
     return userFromAuthToken($request->get('auth-token'));
   }

   return null;
});
```

The problem is, I don't know how to check the default laravel authentication guard before performing my own check

Comment: you wouldn't check the default guard in this new custom guard ... just tell the `auth` middleware to use both guards

Comment: try `config('auth.defaults')['guard']`